# Computing minimum/maximum of multiple variables (more than $3$) with complex equations

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, statistics

I am having a hard time computing a minimum for a very complex equation with multiple variables (like $10$). 
In general, if you want to find the minimum of a certain equation that is convex and differentiable, let us say
$$ \hat{x} = \text{argmin}_x (x^2-2x+1) $$
Here, we can find $\hat{x}$ by derivative of the equation $2x-2=0$.
However, what if we have like 10 variables $x_1 \cdots x_{10} $ with complex equations (even after applying log in the equation) like
$$
\ln\left(f(x_1 \cdots x_{10})\right) = \exp\left\{(3-x_1)^2+x_2(5-x_3)^2 \right\} +x_4 \cdots
$$

in this case, though taking the partial derivative of each $x_i$ all the variables are mixed so seems like this may not be easy to solve...

Is there any technique to solve equations like that?

Any hint will be very much appreciated.

Comment: The same idea applies taking the derivative with respect to each variable separately.

Comment: Yes, the variables are mixed and there won't be a closed-form expression or an exact algorithm for the solution in most cases. The usual way of approaching such problems is with numerical methods. But instead of trying to find the solution of the equations that originate from setting all derivatives to $0$, you would use methods that have been developed specifically for problems like the original optimization problem, like, for example, the [Gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent).